# Please provide the path to the Android SDK: Android SDK path not specified

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sdk-tools

When I run Android Studio, it says

> Please provide the path to the Android SDK: Android SDK path not specified

I tried the to try the solutions that were already posted, but I didn't understand them.

Also, I already have java installed, but I want to word with kotlin.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried to do to fix it

Comment: I am trying to fix the problem but I don't know how

Comment: That error is searchable, no? What exactly have you found that you do not understand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127165/android-studio-3-0-sdk-path-not-specified

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095750/android-sdk-path-not-specified

Comment: I think you want this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Answer (score 4):

Cancel the dialogue box asking for the Android SDK path and do the following:

Open Android Studio IDE.  Find the down arrow icon, should be second last icon in the toolbar.  Click that. You will see a path for Android SDK Location:.  Click the edit link to the right of that.  This will bring up the SDK Components Screen.  If you can check the boxes there, check them. They may already be checked or they may be disabled.  You can leave the path as is, for me its:

```
 C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Depending on whether you had Android Studio before it may say it has detected a previous version and it will only download the components it needs.  This is normal.  Now click the NEXT button.  A confirmation screen will come up with Setup Type and SDK Folder.  If you want to change your SDK Folder this is your last chance, if not, click NEXT again.

It may bring up a Terms & Conditions screen, click the Accept radio button then NEXT. It  will go and download the Android base SDK.  When it's completed click FINISH.

You will then be taken to the Platforms screen where you can select which Android platforms you want to support.  ie, Android 9.0 (Pie), Android 8.1 (Oreo).  Select all the platforms you need then click APPLY.

The downloader will grab all those packages for you.  Next, click the SDK Tools tab.  Check the boxes of the tools you want and click APPLY.  It may bring up a Terms & Conditions screen again, click the Accept radio button then NEXT. When completed just click FINISH and you're good to go.

Comment: Thx for this comment got it working on Linux Mint 19. installed Android Studio via snap but couldn't get it working prior to this, thx again!

Comment: Same on Ubuntu 20.04. All of the SDK Platforms were unchecked. I could not install any of them by checking them as I'd get a message that the SDK is corrupt. Instead I had to click `Edit` next to `Android SDK Location` and then it brought up a Wizard that installed the Android 10 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the Android Studio Plugin for *Kotlin*. When you use the latest version of *Kotlin*, you also have to make sure to update the plugin:

```
Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates
```

Comment: It's working Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the answers mentioned above and at several other threads in Stack overflow did not solve your issue of Android Studio then probably you and I have the same issue. I was stuck here since last 20 days and was struggling over it. Finally able to resolve it. 
Go back to the Android Studio download page. Bottom of the page contains download link to "sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip". Just download the same and extract to a suitable location. Now mention the path to this folder in Android Studio. It will then install the suitable tools for Android Studio to work.

Comment: The problem is that the Android Studio download page says, `These tools are included in Android Studio.` above the links to download the sdk tools. This shouldn't be necessary if that's true, no?

Comment: Same issue here with Android Studio 3.3 for Windows 64-bit. Clean install and it asks for the SDK path.  It provides a link to download the SDK which takes you to the page where you downloaded the 3.3 Studio IDE which claims to have the SDK bundled with it.  Like come on Google. This has been an issue for 2 yrs now. How hard is it to get this right?

Answer (score -1):

You can find the path going into Android Studio -> Configure -> SDK Manager -> On the top left it should say SDK Path.

Usually it is

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

Comment: It's still not working???

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: when I click on SDK Manager, the status of sdk platforms are uninstalled

Comment: It is the same SDK path specified above, but it's still not working

Comment: Appereance & Behaviour -> System settings -> Android SDK  Look for SDK tools tab and check if Android SDK tools is installed

Comment: I tried installing them, but it says that I need to provide an SDK path to be able to install them

Comment: So try to edit path as C:\Users\<Your username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score -1):

Go to SDK Manager under Android SDK location provide the path which you gave during installation. If you had installed by default it should be in your

> C>Users>USERNAME>AppData>Local>Android>SDK.

**NOTE: AppData is hidden by default. So enable hidden items from View.**

Comment: still not working

Comment: Did you download the necessary packages for Android Studio to run?

Comment: I just clicked download android studio normally, but I also have java sdk installed

Comment: Point to the directory which you gave during installation.. You might have created a new Directory for SDK packages to be saved.

Comment: In SDK Manager under SDK tools download Android SDK Build Tools, SDK Platform Tools,SDK Tools, Play Services, USB & Web Driver.

Answer (score -1):

Took me a while to figure this out as the documentation is not clear on this at all.  Cancel the dialogue box asking for the Android SDK path and do the following:

Open Android Studio IDE.  Find the down arrow icon, should be second last icon in the toolbar.  Click that. You will see a path for Android SDK Location:.  Click the edit link to the right of that.  This will bring up the SDK Components Screen.  If you can check the boxes there, check them. They may already be checked or they may be disabled.  You can leave the path as is, for me its:

```
 C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Depending on whether you had Android Studio before it may say it has detected a previous version and it will only download the components it needs.  This is normal.  Now click the NEXT button.  A confirmation screen will come up with Setup Type and SDK Folder.  If you want to change your SDK Folder this is your last chance, if not, click NEXT again.

It may bring up a Terms & Conditions screen, click the Accept radio button then NEXT. It  will go and download the Android base SDK.  When it's completed click FINISH.

You will then be taken to the Platforms screen where you can select which Android platforms you want to support.  ie, Android 9.0 (Pie), Android 8.1 (Oreo).  Select all the platforms you need then click APPLY.

The downloader will grab all those packages for you.  Next, click the SDK Tools tab.  Check the boxes of the tools you want and click APPLY.  It may bring up a Terms & Conditions screen again, click the Accept radio button then NEXT. When completed just click FINISH and you're good to go.